# CSS float left: margin top by minor [perfect fit]

Tags: html, css

I have several comment boxes and I am trying to fit them perfectly.

sample:

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="minor">a</div>
    <div class="major">a</div>
    <div class="minor" style="margin-top: -50px;">a</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    float: left;
    border: 1px #000 solid;
}

.wrapper {
    display: table;
    width: 120px;
    border-style: dotted;
}

.minor {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

.major {
    width: 50px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: 4px;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3JQyb/)

How to leaves them as well only changing the CSS?

[image: expectation]

Comment: Would this not work? http://jsfiddle.net/W7sVL/

Comment: Here you go. You need put a 2 columns that are floated. This is best right solution for future. http://jsfiddle.net/3JQyb/3/

Comment: @JoshCrozier I could float right pairs, but can be cases in which a comment can be 3x higher

Comment: @Foxsk8 In the case of 2 columns, I think I would have to calculate with JS sizes each comment to put on lower column because the sizes are irregular

Comment: Yes. One column for 2 rows is equal of column 2 with 1 row. Here is JS code to set heigts. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9558228

Comment: Like here: http://jsfiddle.net/3JQyb/5/ Fiddle is not take it right.

Comment: I think I can use two class (one for float left and one to the right) and JS I can calculate the total size of the elements and decide what his class. but wanted to find a solution without js. :/

Comment: See this: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/3JQyb/6/

**HTML**

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="major">
            <p class="wrap">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur lacinia ultricies sem, at sollicitudin ligula ultrices nec. In venenatis, libero ac consequat ullamcorper, nunc augue.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="major">
            <p class="wrap">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur lacinia ultricies sem, at sollicitudin ligula ultrices nec. In venenatis, libero ac consequat ullamcorper, nunc augue.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row right">
        <div class="minor">
            <p class="wrap">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur lacinia ultricies sem, at sollicitudin ligula ultrices nec. In venenatis, libero ac consequat ullamcorper, nunc augue.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrap {
    padding: 10px;
}
.table {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.row {
    display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: top;
    height: 100%;
}
.row.right {
    display: block;
}
.major, .minor {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.major {
    height: 50%;
}
.minor {
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

**Edit:**
Fixed an error in the code where the right side box didn't stretch full height if the left side boxes were larger in height.